# Why Amplify forces usage of Identity Pools for federated log in?

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I don't use *Cognito Identity Pools* because I don't need to access AWS resources with the tokens.
I have a couple of federated identity providers configured and through the hosted web UI everything works as expected: I can log in using 3rd party provider and get JWT tokens in response.

However, when trying to achieve the same behavior for login through
`Amplify.Auth.signInWithSocialWebUI` via Amplify on Android, it forces me to add configuration of an Identity Pool to `amplifyconfiguration.json` file.

I don't understand why is it required on Android?